# Why do I have problems with unwrapping and AO baking?

Tags: uv, baking

I have created a rough model of a corrugated iron roof. I need to unwrap it, and then create some shadow maps. However when I DO unwrap it, it looks, extra weird. Just pieces all over the place in the UV image.

And the lamp stops casting any shadows when I set ambient occlusion in my environment.

I followed this : https://community.secondlife.com/t5/Mesh/Ambient-Occlusion-for-Blender-tuts/m-p/2876281#M30051

And it did not work for me.

What do I do ?

Comment: "smart uv project" (as in the tutorial of your link) is supposed to decompose your model face by face preserving their relative surface so. What did you obtained ? Can you show a picture of all that or share your blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions here :

Concerning the UV map it is normal that you obtain "pieces all over the place" when you choose to unwrap with "smart uv project". Some simple explanation are given in this answer : [How to UV unwrap complex models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55739/how-to-uv-unwrap-complex-models/55741#55741)

For the ambient occlusion, it is also normal that AO checked here in your tutorial [image]
makes your shadows lowered or inexistant.

AO will illuminate the environment and make so cavities are darker but also the parts most exposed to the environment lighter. Think about it as if the environment light was stronger than your lamp light.

As Second Life shading works differently from Blender shading, I suggest that you mix your textures (shadow, AO and diffuse) in an image editor tool (like Gimp or equivalent) and import the combined result directly to SL as a diffuse texture.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you. I know you posted a reply a while ago. i forgot this websites name. My roof looks, amazing so thank you again =D